# Play gives "illegal instruction" when running on ubuntu 12.04 LTS

Tags: ubuntu, playframework, vps, playframework-1.x

Recently We started working on a project using play-framework. As my developers are distributed I wanted a common dev environment for them, so I purchased a Xen-VPS server running on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS.

Now When I start running play-framework, it gives an error saying "Illegal Instruction"

Note : I have already set the path to my PLAY_HOME in PATH.

please check the screenshot below

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try running it with full path prefixed.

```
/root/play-1.2.4/play
```

There are rumors play is also a command line command included in Ubuntu to play sounds. Check out you do not have a conflict about that.

If thats is the case, simply rename the play executable or even better, create a link toward the play executable using another name :

```
ln -s /root/play-1.2.4/play /usr/bin/play-framework
```

And check `/usr/bin` is in your path.

Comment: Play 1.x is based on python scripts. Do you have Python installed? Try moving your Play folder to a more "open" folder : /home/yourname.

Comment: yes I have python2.7 installed, the default python which is bundled with ubuntu